# client on one node server on other node but on same host in erlang language

Tags: erlang

Here is the code iam confused when  i was executing in  Erlang shell so please explain me
 In first terminal we set the terminal name as gandalf

```
 erl -sname gandalf
 (gandalf@localhost) 1> kvs:start().
```

In second terminal terminal name is bilbo

```
  erl -sname bilbo
 (bilbo@localhost) 1> rpc:call(gandalf@localhost, kvs,store, [weather, fine]).
```

But the problem is when i was executing the above code in respective terminals code was not getting executed so please explain me and i have one more doubt  is it compulsory to set cookies??

Comment: Can you `net_adm:ping(gandalf@localhost)` beforehand successfully?

Answer (score 2):

Do you [connect node](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/net_kernel.html#connect_node-1) before rpc:call?

Comment: ya i connected but when i was calling rpc module (bilbo@localhost) 1> rpc:call(gandalf@localhost,
kvs,store, [weather, fine]).
the output is bad rpc no node

Comment: what output of nodes(). from both erlang shells?